# How can I copy my MIUI settings-based backup to my PC?

Tags: backup, file-system, miui, mi, xiaomi-mi9

I'm using a Mi 9 SE with MIUI Global 12.5.1.

I've just performed a backup using MIUI's Settings backup mechanism (accessible via Settings > Additional Settings > Backup & Restore); and I see my backup in the "Manage Backps" screen accessible from the hex-nut settings menu.

But - I want to copy these backup files off my phone. Where are the files located?

Answer (score 1):

Well,
the files are within the (Internal Storage) space, under path: MIUI/backup/AllBackup/YYYYMMDD_HHmmNN, where Y is year, M is month, D is day of month, H is hour (24H), m is minutes, and I don't know what N is. Perhaps seconds.

You can easily copy the file, but I've not verified you can them simply copy them to another phone (or to your phone after a reset etc.) and perform a restoration.

Comment: Could you add in your answer in what folder we should put the backup file to restore the app? thx.